# How to overcome with conflicting jQuery files

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, datepicker

I have two jQuery files.

One is for calling datepicker and the other is for calling highchart files.

When I am trying to include both files, my highchart is working and datepicker is not working.

Here is the source code - code for datepicker:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>Date_Component/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>Date_Component/scripts/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>Date_Component/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>Date_Component/scripts/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>Date_Component/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc-ar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>Date_Component/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc-fa.js"></script>
```

Code for hichchart is:

```
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/exporting.js"></script>
```

I have also tried to put the jQuery noconflict to any where of my code I got no result

```
<script type="text/javascript">$.noConflict();</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just include one. The latest version if possible.

Comment: you mean the latest version of jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use only the `jquery's and jquery ui's newer version`,

```
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>Date_Component/scripts/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>Date_Component/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>Date_Component/scripts/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>Date_Component/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc-ar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>Date_Component/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-cc-fa.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/exporting.js"></script>
```

Comment: datepicker is no working with <br />        <script src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

Comment: You have to use latest `datepicker code` from Read http://jqueryui.com/datepicker

Comment: its works greate but when i click on date textbox it shows the pop up calendar at the corner of screen ,i wanna it to show behid of my textbox .

Comment: then i need to changes inside of the code also for date conversion

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
     <script src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var jq = jQuery.noConflict( true );
        //use jq for highchart
     </script>
```

Comment: can you write with details please?

Comment: check this http://interface88.blogspot.in/2012/07/using-multiple-version-of-jquery-on.html

Answer (score 0):

First call jquery

```
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

and Use following code after calling jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jqobj = jQuery.noConflict( true );     
 </script>
```

Comment: i have tried but sounds no result,and can you tell me what is <br /> var jqobj??

Comment: It is a our own shortcut. The noConflict() method returns a reference to jQuery, that you can save in a  variable, for later use like:
jq("button").click(function(){
    jq("p").text("do something");
  });